# Is there a way to configure an Anchor project to use the `--arch sbf` flag without having to specify it with each command?

Tags: anchor, build-bpf, build-sbf

After creating a new Anchor project, when you do `anchor build` you will see this warning:

> Warning: cargo-build-bpf is deprecated. Please, use cargo-build-sbf

After looking into the `cargo build` options, it turns out you can toggle pass in the `--arch sbf` option that switches to `cargo-build-sbf`.

This all seems to work well, but the downside is that I have to specify it on each command (`anchor build --arch sbf`, `anchor test --arch sbf`).

I was wondering if there's a way to configure an Anchor project to use the `sbf` arch by default.

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at the code, and `ProgramArch` isn't included anywhere in the config file at https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/29b8a7280075426a698aeaae3f117f0a609cca15/cli/src/config.rs#L342, so this is not possible.

You could put in a PR to add this to the config somewhere though, maybe at the top-level?